# How to calculate rise time of an Op Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

There is a given op amp circuit with an open loop gain of 100. Rest of the parameters of the op amp is ideal.
The voltage rail of the op amp is +/- 5V.
The input wave form Vi(t) = cos(100t).

So now the question asks to find the rise time (0-100%) of Vo(t).
Can anyone please help me with this question?

[image]

So my attempt was

At t = 0 sec, my output should  be 100xcos (0) = 100V
But since my output voltage cannot go beyond +5V (Vsat), Vo = 5 V.

So I can calculate the final value, but I can’t figure out how to find the rise time. I was thinking for an ideal op amp it should be 0s. But that’s  a wild guess and I’m not really sure.

Comment: You need to try and explain what you have tried to do in order to solve the problem. This site isn't a free homework answering service.

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry was my first questions in SE. I edited it to add my attempt. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a sine or cosine waveform so, assume a sine and ask yourself how many degrees of phase must pass (from 0 degrees and 0 volts) for a sin wave with peak amplitude 100 volts to reach 5 volts. Convert that phase angle to time.

Comment: Is the frequency response of the opamp given? This might be a Laplace Transform based question

Comment: @ijuneja no unfortunately, this is all that’s given

Comment: In that case, Andy aka is correct

Comment: @Andyaka So if I’m correct for the given cos wave the output is going to hit 5V instantly. So rise time should be 0s right?

Comment: Draw your self a picture of a 100 volt sine wave and then superimpose limits at +/- 5 volts.

Comment: I would agree with Andys answer - although the used term "rise time" is defined for a band-limited system and a step input. However, as your amplifier has no band limitation and the input is a cos-signal, Andys interpretation is the only one that makes sense. However, this type of "rise time" is not the rise time "of the opamp" (not determined by the amp) !!

Answer (score 1):

*I'm not giving a full answer because the OP needs to learn.*

Saying that the input is a cosine wave is confusing you. The output will have the same rise and fall times if it were a sine wave except now you can start at t = 0, whence the output waveform begins at 0 volts and 0 degrees of phase angle.

If the amplified waveform was unbounded by the +/- 5 volt rails it would reach  peaks of +/- 100 volts. If you superimpose the 5 volt limits you get something very similar to this: -

[image]

It's a simple matter of using your brain/equipment to calculate arcsin(0.05) to give you the degrees that have passed to hit a level of 5 volts.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: \*begin nitpicking\* It's not just arcsin(0.05) though, the input to the sine wave was 100 *t*, not 1 *t*. \*end nitpicking\*

Comment: @HarrySvensson arcsin(0.05) gives you degrees based on attaining 5% of the peak i.e. 5 volts in 100 volts. You've then got to convert to time by accounting for the frequency.